# I want to Check how to avoid Duplicated title by excluding the spaces,numbers and symbols?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, controller, duplicates

Here what i used in script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function kontroluser() 
        { 
            $('#sonuc_geluser').html('');
            var val = $('#username').val(); //Input'da belirttiğimiz #kullanici_adi ID'sinin değeri 
            $.get('kontrol_user.php?ku='+val, function(data) {
                $('#sonuc_geluser').html(data);
                if(data.length > 8){
                    document.getElementById("test11").disabled = true;
                }else {
                    document.getElementById("test11").disabled = false;
                }
                $('#username').addClass('error');

            }); 
        }  

        </script>
```

and this is my input filed :

```
<input class="text-input small-input required" type="text" name="user_id" placeholder="AP14XXXX" onchange="kontroluser();" id="username"/>
```

then I wrote this PHP code to check duplicate value :

```
<?php 
require_once('includes/config.php');
$ku = $_GET['ku']; 
    $usersQuery = "SELECT user_id FROM user  where user_id='$ku'";
            $users = mysqli_query($link, $usersQuery);
            $kay_Sey = mysqli_num_rows($users);
if($kay_Sey > 0) 
{   
   echo "Username already exists";
}
else {
    echo '';
}
```

?>

,but this one only checks like this for example : when i register new user with id AP1411111 , then when i register another user with same id and put coma like this  **AP141111,** it does not check for duplicate ??? Why

Comment: because the comma makes the field value not unqiue. "API1" != "API1," - if you expect the input to be alphanumeric then you should be validating said input before your query.

Comment: Because they're not duplicates (not-strictly speaking at least). You need to rethink the whole approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yuo can use the php function [similar_text()](http://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_string_similar_text.asp)

```
<?php

similar_text("AP1411111","AP141111,",$percent);
echo $percent;
   //88%

?>
```

You can define a minimum value of difference, let's say, 80%, and if the value is superior to that % assume that's repeated.

An alternative is using the mysql LIKE function:

```
SELECT user_id FROM user where user_id LIKE '%$ku%';
```

The above will match **anything**`AP1411111`**anything**, if you get any result from the DB, assume that's repeated.

**UPDATE:**

Based on your comment, I've updated my answer.
Cleanup any non alphanumeric characters before comparing the string, like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['ku']))
{
$ku = $_GET['ku']; //ex: AP41,113_&xW

$ku = preg_replace('/([^a-zA-Z0-9]+)/i', '', $ku ); //AP41113xW
$ku = preg_replace('/^.*?(AP[0-9]{1,}).*?$/i', '$1', $ku );//AP41113


//the rest of your code

}
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/NHDKtL)

Comment: I have tried this one , also i got the same result. What i want is that exclude any symbols and spaces entered with the user ID and checks only the letters and numbers for duplication !!

Comment: Dear @tuga it worked really thank you for your help I appreciate it :) but there is one thing I try to input this User Id for new user with this one API4111*;@W it didn't show duplicated id , can we solve it ??

Comment: and what about if i only check for alphabetic I mean instead of checking user ID , i want to check titles just alphabetic ??? @tuga

Comment: Can u give me an example ?

Comment: @AhmedKasapbashi It didn't give you duplicated because it matches `API4111W`. does the ID start always with API and has numbers after it ? like API56674 ? if so I can write a new regex to match that.

Comment: Yes Dear bro :) always id starts with "AP" flowed by number like this AP140000 @tuga

Comment: Dear what I mean for titles it's something like this i have an input text like id's but instead of id the user will write the article name for example this title of Article : "Based Local Dominant Feature Extraction Algorithm" so i want it to checks only alphabetic to preventing duplicated title name @tuga

Comment: @AhmedKasapbashi I've update the answer, it should match your needs

Comment: This doesn't match in any way your initial question.

Comment: oh so you mean i write another question ? because you really helped and thank you so much but i need also for checking only alphabetic not alphanumeric.. @tuga